# How to run code after Knockout JS has updated the DOM

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

As part of my view I have:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: caseStudies">
    <li><a data-bind="text: title, attr: { href: caseStudyUrl }"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to run some 3rd Party code once knockout has updated the DOM.

```
caseStudies(data);
thirdPartyFuncToDoStuffToCaseStudyLinks(); <-- DOM not updated at this point.
```

Any idea on how I can hook into knockout to call this at the correct time?

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? Are these properties already present on the caseStudies?

Comment: I don't want to change anything I need a third party library to attach events to the links .

Comment: Could you possibly provide us a Fiddle?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using the `afterRender` binding can help you.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data:caseStudies, afterRender:checkToRunThirdPartyFunction }">
    <li><a data-bind="text: title, attr: { href: caseStudyUrl }"></a></li>
</ul>


function checkToRunThirdPartyFunction(element, caseStudy) {
    if(caseStudies.indexOf(caseStudy) == caseStudies().length - 1){
        thirdPartyFuncToDoStuffToCaseStudyLinks();
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do it if I was using something other than 'foreach', like 'option'?

Comment: @AbdelHady You can use the optionsAfterRender callback: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: This does not work on subsequent updates.. Eg. caseStudies.reverse() does not callback even tho the DOM has changed

Answer (score 18):

One accurate way is to use the fact that KnockoutJS applies bindings sequentially (as they are presented in html). You need define a virtual element after 'foreach-bound' element and define 'text' binding that calls your third party function.

Here is html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: text"></li>
</ul>
<!-- ko text: ThirdParyFunction () -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here is code:

```
    $(function () {
        var data = [{ id: 1, text: 'one' }, { id: 2, text: 'two' }, { id: 3, text: 'three' } ];

        function ViewModel(data) {
            var self = this;
            this.items = ko.observableArray(data);
        }

        vm = new ViewModel(data);
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });

    function ThirdParyFunction() {
        console.log('third party function gets called');
        console.log($('li').length);
    }
```

Comment: afterRender was causing duplicate event triggers, and this approach worked fine for me.

Comment: Dude!! that was just awesome.. Thanks a lot for sharing

Comment: Very important note: I've used this method many times, just make sure you read the value of any observable-changes that would require your code to re-run. example: function ThirdParyFunction(){ this.label(); console.log('run 3rd party code every time label changed'); } otherwise - this code will only run once.