# How to get to the DOM element from a knockout binding?

Tags: knockout.js

I have bound a DOM element to a viewModel using knockout.
When I change a property on the underlying model it changes the DOM - all ok.

However, is there a way to get to the bound DOM element so I can add a class to it when the underlying model gets updated externally?

I have used custom binding which gives me access to the DOM element but I was wondering if there is a simpler way directly from the viewModel's bound property?

Thanks

sample code (TypeScript)

```
SetMyCell(row: number, newValue: any) {

    var ditem = this._DataItems[row];

    // update the actual value    
    ditem.Producer(newValue);

    // Now I wish to decorate the DOM item this Producer property is 
    // bound to with a class. How to go about that?

}
```

Comment: I personally would just data-bind the class of the DOM element. `<div data-bind="attr: { class: functionToDetermineClass }">` Or if you have multiple classes on it that will always be there `<div data-bind="attr: { class: 'class1 class2 ' + functionToDetermineClass() }">`

Comment: Thanks - I have used this technique elsewhere - thing is, I might want to use the DOM for other manipulations where I could really do having a ref to it!  Do you know of any other way (not custom binding)..

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126812/knockout-js-get-dom-object-associated-with-data) might help you

Comment: @jonhopkins - sorry - though interesting, it deals with events where more info is passed to - in my example I update the source through an external event (websocket) so the raw source is all I have to play with...  Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you read the second answer? It gives a way to get the element without any events needing to be triggered, though it assumes you have control over the id of the element. Based on your sample code, it looks like you can probably do this. If not, then I will have to keep searching.

Comment: @jonhopkins Thanks for your help - unfortunately I can't assume anything - I am creating the dom in code on commands from a server - binding also is done when creating each <tr>...  Strange that it is this hard to find the connected DOM elements that are bound to a ko.observable property...

Comment: An observable can be bound to any number of DOM elements. This is especially common with the `checked` binding but could apply to any binding/observable. So although Knockout could hypothetically provide you with that information, the scenario you describe is what bindings are for.

Answer (score 13):

You can abuse the visible binding for example to execute a function passing the $element and $data.

```
<span data-bind="visible: func1($element, $data)">Test span</span>
```

look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhWRS/6/)

I know you mention above that you don't want to use a custom binding but i still want to point out this option. although i am using a custom binding the logic for modifying the element will still happen in the viewmodel when the external changes happen.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.widget = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var elemObservable = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.isObservable(elemObservable)) {
            elemObservable(element);
        }
    }
};

var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    .....
    self.spanElement = ko.observable();
    self.btnClick = function (){
        var elem = self.spanElement();
        $(elem).html("This is the span element");
    };
    ......
};
```

and the html would be

```
<button data-bind="click: btnClick">change element text or something else</button>
<span data-bind="widget: spanElement"></span>
```

I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhWRS/6/) so you can see it in action