# Meaning of $element in Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

What does `$element` means in KnockoutJS. I have seen $element been used in places like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15338183/340046)

```
<span data-bind="visible: func1($element, $data)">Test span</span>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: company, attr: { name: 'company' + $($element).closest('tr').index() }" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$element` is the element DOM object (for virtual elements, it will be the comment DOM object) of the current binding. This can be useful if a binding needs to access an attribute of the current element.

It picks the current DOM object..

e.g.

```
<div id="item1" data-bind="text: $element.id"></div>
```

will return id i.e. item1

read more here :-)

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html