# Knockout js get specific DOM element ID

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i am using the knockout js in my web app,i am getting data from database and binding data using knockout js with checkbox its working, when i checked the checkbox i am getting all related data to it,but i need element ID of all the div when i checked the particular checkbox, is it possible or not ,how i can achieve this need help

```html
<div data-bind="foreach:items">
  <ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
      <span id="txtuserID" data-bind="text:userId" style="display:none"></span>
      <span id="txtuserName" style="margin-top: 10px;font-size: 22px;font- weight: bold;padding-left:0px;" data-bind="text:username"></span>
      <div data-bind="attr:{id:$index()}, Image({image});" class="Image">
     <div id="img1"><img src=1.png /><div>
     <div id="img2"><img src=2.png /><div>
     <div id="img3"><img src=3.png /><div>
       </div>
      <input id="chkID" type="checkbox" data-bind="value:userId(), checked: $root.addItemTitle, click: $root.toggle" /></li>
    <ul>
</div>

 <!-- language: lang-js -->

function UserDetails() {
  var self = this;

  function(userId username) {
    var self = this;
    self.userId = userId;
    self.username = ko.observable(username)
    self.Image=ko.computed(function() {
    return this.Image() + " " + this.Imagetype();
  }, this);
  }

  }
  self.addItemTitle = ko.observable();
  //Check Box Selected
  self.toggleAssociation = function(item, event) {
    if (item.Selected() === true) console.log("dissociate item " + item.userId());
    else console.log("associate item " + item.UserID() + " " + "UserName " + item.UserName(), "you clicked " + event.target.id);
    /// here i am getting userID,Username and checkbox element id=chkid, is   it possible to get userName elementID
    item.Selected(!(item.Selected()));
    return true;
  };
   }
```

Comment: The `jquery` tag has been removed as it's irrelevant...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get to the DOM element from a knockout binding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071111/how-to-get-to-the-dom-element-from-a-knockout-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate through the HTML domain you can use these 2 JS methods

```
event.target.parentElement //Returns the parent object
event.target.children //Returns Children
```

so you can do this:

```
var li = event.target.parentElement;
```

with that you have acess to all your objects in relation to the checkbox. To get the div children you can do this:

```
var liChild = li.children;
```

that returns an array of all the elements inside the div.

to get all the ids you can do this:

```
function getIDs(array) {
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        output[i] = array[i].id;
    }
    return output;
}
```

and then

```
var ids = getIDs(liChild);
```

if you want to get the div you can do this

```
var li = event.target.parentElement;
var ul = li.parentElement;
var div = ul.parentElement;
var divChild = div.children;
var divIDs = getIDs(divChild);
```

> **EDIT : Here goes the new code for your edit**

Ok, with your edit you've introduced a div that holds other divs, my awnser still holds true, but with a few enhancements. You can still use .children and .parentElement to find those elements.

```
var li = event.target.parentElement; //Finds parent element
var imageDiv = li.getElementsByClassName('Image')[0]; //Finds the "Image" Div (the zero is there because .getElementByClass returns an array)
var imageChild = imageDiv.children; //Gets the children
var ids = getIDs(imageChild); //Gets the IDs of the children
```

Comment: @thanks,but i have secnario that,i have div with class Image,i am binding my image,creating new div inside it with ID img1, so how i can get that img1,img2,img3 ID,i have change the code above

Comment: thanks, but var "imageDiv = li.getElementByClass('Image')[0];", i am getting error "Uncaught TypeError: li.getElementByClass is not a function"

Comment: i'm so sorry, the function is  getElementsByClass, forgot an 's' and if that dosn't work try getElementsByClassName

Comment: did you try  getElementsByClassName?

Comment: no problem mate, my bad I got the function wrong, shoud've looked into docummentation :)

Comment: can i get specific div ID lik first div ID

Comment: once you have the ID array, you can reference to the index of the div, for example ids[0] is the first index, it is the id for img1, ids[1] is the sencond index, it references to the id of img2

Comment: @thanks, i was change code in for loop so it was not working,now its working has i required thanks for your time

Comment: @isaadev,i have small change in above example,i am generating id using $index() which generate new random id,now i want to get element by that ID is it possible,similar to class,but  random generating ID